# How to get the message id of the email message before sending using Exchange Web Service(JAVA)?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

Need to track the emails so before sending emails I need to get the message id of the email message.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to save the `EmailMessage` first before you send it.

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(service);
emailMessage.save();
```

EWS saves the email message and assigns an [Internet message identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.internetmessageid?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_EmailMessage_InternetMessageId) to it. But on your local `emailMessage` this property still isn't set. Trying to access it by

```
emailMessage.getInternetMessageId();
```

will result in a `ServiceObjectPropertyException`. You need to get the remote and updated  version of the email message:

```
emailMessage = EmailMessage.bind(service, emailMessage.getId());
```

Now you can read the Internet message identifier property. Set other properties as needed and then send the message.

Comment: Still I am facing issue, Argument Item id is not valid. Could you please post the working example for getting message id.

Comment: It's confusing if you speak of _Item id_ and _message id_. These are two different properties. The first is an `ItemId` which is a property of an `Item`. The second is only a property of an `EmailMessage`. In order to show a working example show please first your code where the error occours.

Comment: Getting error after execution of bind . Error is   (java.lang.Exception) java.lang.Exception: Argument itemId not valid.

Comment: Since you didn't posted your code nor the stacktrace it's  impossible for me to tell what follows _after execution of bind_ and causes the error. But it doesn't look like an exception thrown by EWS.